# Does Hibernare Envers support model classes that use mappings?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

So far I've not seen any examples where the classes are using hibernate mapping. They all seem to use annotations. Would it work if I use mappings to wire the classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. The unique way to work with Envers is by annotations.

Look: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3887

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't sure if you mean't configure Envers auditing within the hbm files or just add Envers within the application.

- If you need to configure within hbm, **no** is not possible as Rafael Zeffa previous answered. [See this issue for reference](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3887)
- If you need to use Evers within a existing Application that has it's entities mapped with hbm.xml files, It's possible, you just need to add the Envers annotations as needed. I've created a sample application demonstrating this. You can download it [here](https://github.com/andrezimmermann/sample-hibernate-hbm-envers)