# Hibernate Auditing with hbm

Tags: java, hibernate, audit-logging

Can someone suggest me some [hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate) [auditing-framework](/questions/tagged/auditing-framework) for Java web application which should support for existing [hbm](/questions/tagged/hbm) files in my application.

After searching on the web I found that auditing with [envers](/questions/tagged/envers) is one of the best solution, but it doesn't seems to helping me with my application which is already developed using hibernate [hbm](/questions/tagged/hbm) files (No annotation has been used).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you can use Envers with an application that uses hbm files:  https://github.com/andrezimmermann/sample-hibernate-hbm-envers and [Does Hibernare Envers support model classes that use mappings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27572785/does-hibernare-envers-support-model-classes-that-use-mappings/27573014#27573014)

Comment: Thanks @Alexandru Marina. I implemented auditing functionality using Hibernate Intercepters.